# Explain this interaction between a traveller, a boy and a bag of bread in Nepal?

Tags: nepal, kathmandu, scams

I aimlessly bumped into [a youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QS5uZFhgnKk). A traveller in Nepal seemed to call the poor little boy hiding behind a post an idiot? I don't understand what has happened between them? Is it a local scam or something?

Comment: Were you actually in Nepal when this happened? That would make it a LOT more interesting than if you were just watching YouTube from say, England or the United States.

Answer (score 6):

Where there's tourism there's likely to be beggars - especially in poorer countries.

Sometimes these beggars will be "real" - people who are homeless and in need of help from others to survive.  Sometimes they are simply trying to swindle money from tourists, often as part of a larger ring - especially when children are involved.  Some people claim that the best way to help such people is to give them food rather than money - with the logic that if they are truly homeless and in need of help, then they will be thankful for the food.

In this case it would appear the tourist has simply found someone who is not in need of food.  He gave the food to the boy, the boy didn't want/need it, so he disposed of it by giving it to the dog.

Attempting to video the child and calling him an "idiot" benefits nobody, but unfortunately is the type of action you often see from some tourists.